Can a GCP BigQuery Table Description include a link?
We are trying to be diligent about providing table (and field) descriptions in BigQuery.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#updating_a_tables_description
One thing we want to do is include a link to where more documentation can be found.   I am building that link in the same terraform that creates the table.
Am I correct in assuming there is no way to make this link clickable?

If I include HTML or Markdown in the description field, it is displayed as text.
I'm also open to alternative approaches - the goal is simply to have someone who is in BigQuery know where to look for more documentation.

Currently Bigquery does not support clickable links in table descriptions. However, there is a feature request filed for the same. You can vote for this feature by clicking the +1 and STAR mark to receive updates on it.

The nature of a BigQuery table is that when it is created, we can contemplate that Google creates a "record" in the internal of what we know as BigQuery.  This record contains (presumably) the name of the table, which data blocks constitute the table, the schema of the table, ACLs and more.  We can think of this as the "meta data" of your BigQuery table (i.e. the data that describes the data (i.e. the table)).
The description information is merely a field in this record.  It is of type string and is used to hold some human readable information.  However, that doesn't mean it is any kind of "rich text" ... no links, no bolds, no fonts ... just text (string).  As such, the Console UI doesn't try and interpret its content other than as text.  So the blunt answer to your question is "no" ... the description associated with the table won't be able to hold a hyper link.
However ... there is a much better answer.  Google has a companion service called Dataplex (Google Dataplex).  Dataplex is Google's solution for data governance.  The notion of data governance is to provide you with the tools to manage your data.  A key notion of managing that data is to provide rich descriptions of it and to make it easily discoverable and understandable.  When you enable Dataplex (and a component within it called Data Catalog), when a table is created, a new Dataplex record is automatically created.  Think of the Dataplex Data Catalog record is being "uber" metadata.  Unlike the metadata of a BigQuery table, the Data Catalog record can be used to describe (and be associated with) a wide variety of data ... not just BigQuery.  As such, it can be used with BigQuery tables, Google Cloud Storage buckets, Spark tables, PubSub topic and more.  The Data Catalog record DOES contain rich text capacilities including hyper links and markdown.  It is where you can/should store the documentation, usage, lineage, ownership and other information pertaining to managing your data.

Thanks, @kolban.   I would love to use Dataplex and Data Catalog, but the institution where I work has existing data governance processes, as well as metadata and data dictionary tools that have a broader scope than our data lake in GCP.   These are what I was hoping to link to.    My concern with going BigQuery -> Dataplex / data catalog -> institutional tools is adding to the number of places where information has to be maintained.
